# How to get Supervisor or Senior Developer to check and review your work ?

Tags: programmer

As being freelancer the biggest drawback for newcomer would be to be supervised for their work.

Last day I had interview and they apology to get me hired because I do freelancing.

It is almost understood that Freelancer's mostly don't have polished work who never got chance to do job under someone's supervision.

My Question is that How a freelancer who could make anything asked for but cannot guaranty whether the written code meet quality standards or not, can fill this gap? How could freelancers get their work supervised by someone to point out their mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

> It is almost understood that Freelancer's mostly don't have polished work who never got chance to do job under someone's supervision.

Sorry. It's **not** "understood". In fact, I find it quite *rude* if someone approaches me for work assuming I don't know what I'm doing.

**If anything, the "understanding" would be that a freelancer has enough practical, real-world, experience to complete their work in a *polished and professional* manner.**

What you are describing is a *hobbyist*, not a *freelancer*.

If you don't have any real-world experience, you need to get some. Daniel points out a few ways in his answer as well.

- Get a real job in the field you want to freelance in.
- Hire an experience professional in your field to review your work, and be prepared to redo it.
- Get a formal education
- Worst case, disclose to potential clients that you have no practical, real-world experience.

If you can't do any of the above, then in my opinion, you should *not* be "freelancing".

Truth of the matter is you should *not* be asking others to pay you if you have no practical experience, and aren't disclosing that fact up front. Doing so only serves to *devalue* the *entire field* you are attempting to work in. In short, you give *everyone* a bad name if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I appreciate what you said. I think may be the question reflects that. But my point is not about having real world problems. Client normally needs output. Normal programmer can do a job without following any design patterns even without following standard rules. Real world experience is not my point. my point is about not following the coding standards which have been developed now days.

Answer (score 1):

Option one: Hire a known expert in your field to do some training/review etc.

Option two: Get a recognized degree in your field. That is really the whole point to MCSE program and the like: To guarantee that the owner is able to produce work up to a certain standard.

Option three: Build/Join a network of freelancers where you can have mutual support and discussions of the more difficult problems.

Option four: Start publishing yourself, speak at conferences etc. Publishing your ideas and parts of your work will get you a ton of feedback and attention as well. If you are in fact good at your field you will in time become yourself a "known expert".

Comment: I like the idea of self branding. Best option is Video Blogs. I guess? or any other option available? Conferences are not so common here.

Comment: I don´t know if video is the right medium for (I am assuming software?) development. You can start with simply answering stack-overflow questions. Blogs, tutorials and open-source work would be my next bet. If you have enough material maybe a book?

But you have to decide for yourself. Maybe I´m just old-fashioned ;)

Comment: You are right. But for all that (other then answering question) You need another skill to master which is technical writing. I am not good at that as well but working on it. May be at that stage we could hire some content writer to write what I want to deliver right? It is kind of slow process but still does not guaranty the quality work. No supervision only the noise of feedback which may or may not be correct. :(

Comment: You don´t need technical writing skills for open source work. I agree publishing blogs or a book is not for everyone.